# php how to add new line to string

Tags: php, string

I want to add new line to an existing string I tried this way

```
$filename = 'popups-'.$jsonData['name'].'.js';
$text = $jsonData['text'].'\n';
```

However I get `\n` directly append in the string instead of a new line
What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Vazgen Makaryan did you checked the answer?

Answer (score 4):

you should use double quotes for this

```
$filename = 'popups-'.$jsonData['name'].'.js';
$text = $jsonData['text']."\n";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php